# Unnest all the arrays on bigquery and sum some of them

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with a big table with a lot of arrays.
I need to unnest all the arrays and sum some of them and avoid over counting

[image]

I tried a lot of thing. last try(just a few columns, I have like 30):

```
SELECT DISTINCT country, column1, SUM(DISTINCT column2), SUM(DISTINCT column3)
FROM `table`,
UNNEST(column1) column1,
UNNEST(column2) column2,
UNNEST(column3) column3
ORDER BY country, column1
```

It's take a lot of time to process that query(more than 15 minutes) and I think it's over counting some columns.
(The query process 6.55 MB when run)

Is any better way to unnest all the arrays and sum some of them?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I cannot share the table. The minimal code is on the main question.

Comment: Lol. No one really need your real data. Just provide any dummy data that illustrate your case. Read link in my above comment

Comment: I know that :) But I can't share the table because I can't upload files. I'm a new user.Is a big table with a lot of arrays and each array has like 25 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of sub-queries on top of arrays instead of cross-joining everyting.

E.g.

```sql
SELECT
  country, 
  column1, 
  SUM( (select sum(c2) from unnest(column2) as c2) ) c2sum, 
  SUM( (select sum(c3) from unnest(column3) as c3) ) c3sum
FROM `table`, unnest(column1)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Getting rid of cross joins (the commas in your FROM statement) will make everything faster.